# Parse login not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using this code from Parse:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:namerL password:passerL
                                block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                    if (user) {
                                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signinToInbox" sender:self];
                                    } else {
                                        NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed." message:@"Invalid Username and/or Password." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                        [alert show];
                                    }
                                }];
```

Whenever I click on the sign in button without typing in anything, it doesn't log any errors. I need it to count it as an error if there is no such user and or if the password is correct. But even if the account details are not correct, it is still going to the segue.

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` I believe that it's calling the segue because it is still in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I just don't know how to stop it from calling the segue that's connected it (by default).

Comment: Check if user != [NSNull null] as well. I think even if log in fails, API returns null object in user.

Comment: @Rahul Hmm, there seems to be something else going on. When I delete the segue code, it still does it. It is inside `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{` So I think that might be it right? And by the way, the segue is a modal.

Comment: Are you sure that `namerL` and `passerL` are nil? I just tried my app, I get `Error: invalid login credentials` - `Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19`

Comment: @WilliamGeorge It's not nil. For example when I log @"namer %@" all it gives it namer. And if I just do @"%@", it doesn't show any log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this problem isn't about parse login at all.  From the comments, it seems to be about segues attached to table view cells.

If you want to perform a segue conditionally, it shouldn't be attached directly to the table view cell.  Instead draw the segue between view controllers in IB (ctrl-drag from the view controller's status bar to the destination vc).  Give that segue a name, like "goodLogin", then perform it manually upon a condition.

So if you only want to segue when a login succeeds ...

```
// parse login
    if (!error) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goodLogin"];
    } else {
        // don't perform a segue.  Stay here and change ui to indicate an error
    }
```

Comment: I tried ctr-dragging from the view controller to the code, but it doesn't let me.

Comment: ctrl drag from one view controller (not from a table view cell, from it's parent view controller) to another view controller, not to the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        [self loggedInSuccessfully];
    } else {
        [self loginFailedWithError:error];
    }
}];
```

When doing any API call, I would always check the `error` variable because if it exists then you know the method failed.

**EDIT**

From our discussion it appears that you are having problems with your `UITableView` performing the `segue` when you click on a cell.

It is possible to disable a segue by returning `NO` from the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender 
{
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"signinToInbox"]){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This will disable all `segues` on the `UIViewController` apart from your `signinToInbox`

However, I believe you may have your `UIStoyboard` set up incorrectly, there shouldn't be the default `segue` enabled. You should only need to perform the `segue` in the code after you have called the login function. Therefore in the storyboard you should be using the custom segue option.

If you have a `segue` set up already on the `UIStoryboard` you should be able to click on it and in the `Attributes inspector` panel change the drop down from `model` to `custom`

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't fix it. Since it's in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` I believe that it's calling the segue because it is still in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I just don't know how to stop it from calling the segue that's connected it (by default).

Comment: Oh okay. I clearly misunderstood the question. How have you set up the segue. In the storyboard? You can always use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` to disable it. Could you update the question to be a little clearer? Perhaps post the `didSelectRow` code.

Comment: Ok. How do I use shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:? Do you mean use instead of didselectrow?

Comment: @user3398659 I have updated my answer with a response to your new question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have problems with your segues and table views. Try the following in Xcode 6.
First delete your current segue.
Ctrl + drag as shown:
[image: ctrl+drag segue]

After that, choose the action segue you want (push, modal or custom). Then make sure the identifier matches the one in the code.

[image: identifier]

Now simply make the following changes in the code

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:namerL password:passerL block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signinToInbox" sender:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error logging in: %@",error);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"In valid username and/or password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show]; 
     }
 }];
```